# Set Dependency Property without calling ChangeEvent

Tags: c#, wpf, events, dependency-properties

I'm working on a bigger project and have to work with dependency properties...
Now i need to change the value of my dp but do not want to get the event fired.

is it possible to break this event - chain?

Or can i change the dp without firing the event?

Cause it's not possible to say -> `e.Handled= true`

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? One of the goals of dependency properties is to be notified when they changed...

Comment: Can you tell me what do you mean by `event` here?

Comment: For example he has implemented this: 
`public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowDeadbandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ShowDeadband", typeof(bool), typeof(CreateEditInVariableControl), new PropertyMetadata(true));`

But i need to change this variable without getting a call back with name "xy_Changed".

Comment: `xy_Changed` isn't registered with that dependency property, so what? Anyway, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13449676/1136211

Comment: @Clemens : Thanks, but there is still no solution. 
Or is this still not possible? I mean, if i change one property he calls over 400 "changed" functions...and i need to prevent this.

Comment: If you change the value of a dependency property with a registered PropertyChangedCallback, the callback is inevitably called. All you can do is set an internal flag before changing the property value, and react on that flag in the callback method.

Comment: @Clemens :  i forgot to answer the half.... now it seems not to be registered, but he calls it i do not know why and where...

Comment: @Clemens : Okay, thanks. =)